# JSS NextJS GraphQL.d.ts code gen best practice

Tags: jss, graphql

Sitecore `NextJS` sample generates the `*.d.ts` file. The size of this file is pretty big. It uses graphql-let behind the scene.

https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/tree/release/19.0.0/samples/nextjs/src

Keen understand best practices around this code gen:

1. Does every component that has `graphQL` query file needs to generate this giant `*.d.ts` file?
2. Is there any best practice around centralizing this generated code and re-use or is it tightly coupled to a specific `*.graphql` file?
3. Do we need to generate this file all `*.grapql` files or is it case by case?